# How do I show "sharing/action" extensions in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I'm not trying to create a custom extension - I just want to know how to show the app extensions popup.

In my app, someone will tap a custom UIButton and I don't know what code I need to use to show the popup for sharing/actions.

All the documentation I've seen online mentions creating a custom extension, and nothing about showing the defaults. Maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.

Comment: I think you're asking about `UIActivityViewController`. [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) has a reasonably complete article on it.

Comment: Fantastic - post this as an answer, and I'll check it. - If you care to.

Comment: may I know why you do not want to use the default Share button?